# Combining a table created and a Listagg query

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

currently I have two sections of code, one to create a table, the other to listagg the table. The code looks something like this:

```
Create table NewTable nologging as
select  distinct x as customerNumber,
y as items bought,
z as prices
from 
    customerNum,
    numItems,
    itemPrice
where  (z not in ('2.00','3.00','NA'))
```

and then a Listagg that follows

```
create table formattingSection nologging as
select newTable.customerNumber, listagg(newTable.bought,',') within group (order 
by bought) as boughtdesc
from newTable
group by customerNumber
```

Is it possible to combine these two sections into one section? so that way I do not have 2 tables?

Comment: you forgot to ask an actual question

Comment: I don't think you need to create ANY tables. your data is coming from customerNum, numItems, and itemPrice. leave the data there where it belongs, and create one or more VIEWs against it as needed

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax

Comment: @GordonLinoff even if he had followed your NEVER rule, it's still bad, there's no actual predicates, ANSI or Oracle joins

Comment: @thatjeffsmith . . . If you use `JOIN`, you need an `ON` clause.  Hence, the OP could then figure out that the conditions are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, I presume:

```
create table formattingSection nologging as
select 
  customerNumber, 
  listagg(bought, ',') within group (order by bought) as boughtdesc
from 
  -- instead of "newTable" itself, use SELECT statement from "CREATE TABLE newTable"
  (select distinct x as customerNumber,
                   y as items bought,
                   z as prices
   from 
     customerNum,
     numItems,
     itemPrice
   where (z not in ('2.00', '3.00', 'NA'))
     -- and ... --> you should join those tables, somehow. Otherwise, Cartesian product 
     -- will be created, and that's probably not what you want. 
  )
group by customerNumber;
```

Apart from comments I wrote in the code, "z" column seems to represent "price", and it seems that you store it into a `VARCHAR2` column. I'd suggest you not to do it; use `NUMBER` datatype. Why? Because nothing stops you from entering prices as "x.%i" or "2=&3". If such as decision was made because of "NA", no problem - you'd just leave it *empty*, its value would be NULL. For displaying purposes, you'd `DECODE` such a value: `decode(z, null, 'NA', z)`.